# How to Attach Master Page into A New ASPX / HTML Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, master-page

I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2013 and I want to make a new page using either in ASPX or HTML. So, I did make a new ASPX page called test_1.aspx, and I typed only

```
<h1>Helloooo</h1>
```

just to make sure that it works fine once it loaded. And then, I press F12 and it did work!
But it only showed that "Helloooo" text without the header and sidebar I used to see on other pages. So I did some search about adding the master page, and did this:

- Open the test_1.aspx page in editing mode
- Go to Style - Attach - Default Master Page (currently: seattle.master)
- Match Content Regions dialog opened - click OK
- And then, it was processing the page, and I got some new lines on my test_1.aspx page

I saved and run it on the browser, but then it display the error page : "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred.", and I clicked the Technical Detail, it contains this :

> Correlation ID: dc1d259c-35f4-40e6-e866-a5d2a8a463a2

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is causing this error? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried searching the SharePoint logs for the correlation id? The message you see in the page is too generic, you need to find out the actual error message. Anyway, if I had to make a guess at the problem... I would say that the page does not match the expected content place holders of the selected master page.

Comment: I've tried to search the logs, well, I didn't know how exactly to search the log before, but then I search about it and did what stated in this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/242586/Easily-Determining-what-is-the-exact-Error-by-usin , but apparently the Sharepoint 2010 Administration Toolkit didn't seem to work, I guess because I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: And this link: http://blog.credera.com/topic/technology-solutions/microsoft-solutions/troubleshooting-sharepoint-errors/ , in this tutorial, the Sharepoint Log Viewer did show up but when I typed my correlation id on the Search Box, it didn't show any error message. Do you have any suggestion to see the error?

Comment: Well.. SharePoint log infrastructure uses multiple file. Maybe when you reviewed the logs with SP Log Viewer SharePoint had already switched the current file to a new one. Have you already tried to replicate the error while keeping the log viewer open in the background? That way when you receive a new correlation id you should be able to find it in the already opened log viewer window.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<form> </form` from the page after you add the master - the master has a `<form>`in it and and you passing two forms for the same page.

At least I think that's it.